# Convert String to array without using explode in php

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I want to save string as an array in mongoDB database.
I get following string and I need to convert it to array for storing data in mongoDB database.
 I am using codeigniter framework.

Input String

```
"[ [ 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ] ]"
```

Desired Output

```
[ 
    [ 
        18, 
        18, 
        18, 
        18, 
        18, 
        18, 
        18, 
        18, 
        18
    ], 
    [ 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2
    ], 
    [ 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2
    ], 
    [ 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2
    ], 
    [ 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2
    ], 
    [ 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2
    ], 
    [ 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2
    ], 
    [ 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2
    ], 
    [ 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2, 
        2
    ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks like JSON, so why not use a JSON parser?

Comment: It's a string so it's not work, i try that.

Comment: @Ranpariya ?!?! JSON is a *string* format. I just tried it in a parser and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That looks like JSON, so why not use a JSON parser?
>
> It's a string so it's not work, i try that.

It is indeed a JSON string, contrary to your claim :)

```
<?php

print_r( json_decode("[ [ 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 ] ]"));
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/270562)**

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => 18
            [2] => 18
            [3] => 18
            [4] => 18
            [5] => 18
            [6] => 18
            [7] => 18
            [8] => 18
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [6] => 2
            [7] => 2
            [8] => 2
        )

)
```